# STM32F4 SPI issue: master cannot write data

Tags: c, embedded, driver, stm32, spi

I am trying to write SPI driver for STM32F407 MCU and use this driver to send data to Arduino.

Below is the part of the application that send data to Arduino.
(STM32F4 is acting as a master, hardware slave management is used.)

```
int main (void)
{
    /*initilize green led on PD12*/
    green_led_init();

    /*Initialize user button on PA0*/
    user_button_init();

    /*Initilize SPI2 on PB15:PB12*/
    SPI2_GPIO_pin_init();
    SPI2_init();
    SPI_NSS_pin_ctr(SPI2,ENABLE);

    char *dataPtr = "HelloWorld";
    uint8_t dataLength = strlen(dataPtr);

    while(1){
        if(user_button_read()){
            green_led_on();
            SPI_periph_ctr(SPI2,ENABLE);

            /*send to Arduino size of data to receive. then send the data*/
            SPI_send_data(SPI2,&dataLength,1);
            SPI_send_data(SPI2,(uint8_t*)dataPtr,dataLength);

            /*check whether SPI2 is still busy. if not, disable SPI2*/
            while(SPI_busy_check(SPI2));
            SPI_periph_ctr(SPI2,DISABLE);
        }else{
            green_led_off();
        }
    }
```

Here is the API for sending data

```
void SPI_send_data (SPI_TypeDef *SPIxPtr, uint8_t *txBufferPtr, uint32_t Length)
{
        uint8_t temp = 0;
        while(Length){
            /* wait until tx buffer is empty*/
            while(!SPIxPtr->SR & SPI_SR_TXE);

            if(!(SPIxPtr->CR1 & SPI_CR1_DFF)){
                /*8 bit data frame*/
                SPIxPtr->DR = *txBufferPtr;
                txBufferPtr++;
                Length--;
            }else{
                /*16 bit data frame*/
                SPIxPtr->DR = *((uint16_t*)txBufferPtr);
                txBufferPtr+=2;
                Length-=2;
            }
        }
}
```

As I try to write data to DR register, value of DR register keep being 0xFF, and the RXNE bit in SR register bit keep being set (please follow this link for images https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoNX9.jpg). Since this application only send data to Arduino and since data is being sent, I believe the TXE bit should be clear, not RXNE being set.

I still cannot figure out why the above happen. Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: You may be overlooking that SPI is effectively always bidirectional; it's just that you have the option of *ignoring* the receive data in situations where that is not meaningful.   It's not clear that you have an actual "problem" here or if so what the failure is.  You might try unmodified example code or at least using someone else's proven library rather than immediately trying to DIY, look at the SPI lines with a scope or cheapy logic analyzer or see how things look from the Arduino's perspective.

Comment: As said by @ChrisStratton, you might not have a problem at all :). At least it's normal that RXNE is set.  You're not receiving bytes on the Arduino ?

Comment: this process is true . when your master spi_clk 8 clock pulse sent ,in MOSI 8bit data has been sent and in MISO 8 bit data has been revived too.maybe  received data be  0x00 or 0xff but it is good reason to found out 8bit data has been completely sent

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the SPI up the debugger while using SPI, I highly recommend NOT doing, since the debugger will keep on reading the DR registry to update the GUI in the IDE, which then messes up the status-flags.

Even if not using the HAL library from ST, you can always use it as a reference

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
{
...........
   while (hspi->TxXferCount > 0U)
    {
      /* Wait until TXE flag is set to send data */
      if(__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXE))
      {
        *((__IO uint8_t*)&hspi->Instance->DR) = (*pData);
        pData += sizeof(uint8_t);
        hspi->TxXferCount--;
      }
      else
      {
        /* Timeout management */
        if((Timeout == 0U) || ((Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY) && ((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) >=  Timeout)))
        {
          errorcode = HAL_TIMEOUT;
          goto error;
        }
      }
    }
...........
 /* Wait until TXE flag */
  if(SPI_WaitFlagStateUntilTimeout(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXE, SET, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
  {
    errorcode = HAL_TIMEOUT;
    goto error;
  }

  /* Check Busy flag */
  if(SPI_CheckFlag_BSY(hspi, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
  {
    errorcode = HAL_ERROR;
    hspi->ErrorCode = HAL_SPI_ERROR_FLAG;
    goto error;
  }

  /* Clear overrun flag in 2 Lines communication mode because received is not read */
  if(hspi->Init.Direction == SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES)
  {
    __HAL_SPI_CLEAR_OVRFLAG(hspi);
  }
...........
}
```